# Cannot POST /user/register

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, postman

I'm trying to learn MEAN stack with a tutorial and I'm sticking in some point when I tried to test post method with POSTMAN I've searched and tried many ways and can't find the answer yet.

Codes are : app.js

```
const express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

const users = require('./routes/users'),
    config = require('./config/database');

//Connect to database
mongoose.connect(config.database);
//On Connection
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('Connected to database : ' + config.database);
});
//On Error
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('Database error : ' + err);
});

const app = express();

//Port number
const port = 3000;

//Cors Middleware
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/users', users);

//Index route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Invalid response');
});
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Invalid response');
})

//Start Server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server stated with port : ' + port);
});
```

Route code: users.js

```
const express = require('express'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'),
    router = express.Router();

const User = require('../models/user');

//Register
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
    let newUser = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        username: req.body.username,
        passowrd: req.body.passowrd
    });

    User.addUser(newUser, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ success: false, msg: 'Failed to register user!' });
        } else {
            res.json({ success: true, msg: 'User Registered' });
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Model code: user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    bcrypt = require('bcryptjs'),
    config = require('../config/database');

//User Schema
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    passowrd: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports.addUser = function (newUser, callback) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.passowrd, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            newUser.passowrd = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);
        });
    });
}

const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

POSTMAN config :

Method : POST

URL
    http://localhost:3000/users/register

Header
    key: Content-Type , 
    value: application/json

```
Body
{
    "name": "Wai Lin Aung",
    "email": "wailinaung@mail.com",
    "username": "Wai Lin",
    "passowrd": "123456"
}
```

POSTMAN output:

HTML

```
Cannot POST /user/register
```

JSON :
    Unexpected '<'

Terminal Log:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
/Users/wailin/Documents/Projects/meanauthapp/app.js:41
app.post('/', (req,res))
            ^

ReferenceError: req is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/wailin/Documents/Projects/meanauthapp/app.js:41:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:393:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:508:3
```

Updated Log:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Server stated with port : 3000
Connected to database : mongodb://localhost:/27017/meanauth
TypeError: User.addUser is not a function
    at router.post (/Users/wailin/Documents/Projects/meanauthapp/routes/users.js:17:10)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/wailin/Documents/Projects/meanauthapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/wailin/Documents/Projects/meanauthapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/wailin/Documents/Projects/meanauthapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/wailin/Documents/Projects/meanauthapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/wailin/Documents/Projects/meanauthapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/wailin/Documents/Projects/meanauthapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/wailin/Documents/Projects/meanauthapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/Users/wailin/Documents/Projects/meanauthapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/Users/wailin/Documents/Projects/meanauthapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/wailin/Documents/Projects/meanauthapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/wailin/Documents/Projects/meanauthapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/wailin/Documents/Projects/meanauthapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/wailin/Documents/Projects/meanauthapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/wailin/Documents/Projects/meanauthapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/wailin/Documents/Projects/meanauthapp/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:129:5
```

Comment: In app.js, your have defined middleware as: `app.use('/users', users)`. So, shouldn't your API be: `http://localhost:3000/users/register` instead of `http://localhost:3000/user/register`?
Notice the extra 's' in user**s**.

Comment: Oh I forgot the 's'. But it didn't solve the problem too. It's now showing me that     TypeError: User.addUser is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error below is in the app.js.

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
/Users/wailin/Documents/Projects/meanauthapp/app.js:41
app.post('/', (req,res))
```

AFAIK req, res are properties from express.Router(). But you just call this in your router-files but not in your app.js

Comment: I did called in app.js  ` app.post('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('Invalid response');
    })`

Comment: Yes, but try calling this `const router = express.Router();` somewhere after `express = require('express')`

Comment: Can you please tell me more exactly. I'm not sure that which file you are telling about. If it is users.js, I already called it. And I think it's not the problem now. The log is saying that TypeError: User.addUser is a function. See the Updated Log:

Comment: Oh sorry, first your error seems to point to the index routes in your app.js.
I think the line `const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);` in your model overwrites your addUser function? 

I'm not a big fan of putting functions in your model. I would recommend to put the addUser function into the route - file.